# How do I use Steam Coupons?

Tags: steam

All those coupons I got from the Gift Pile event are about to become valid, so I might as well ask: How do I actually use them?

Do I sort of activate them from my Inventory, or can I select them at some point during checkout?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [Support Article](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4210-YIPC-0275&l=english)

> Steam will apply any of your applicable coupons automatically. Prior to clicking “purchase,” you can choose to save your coupon for later by clicking the “Change/Remove coupon” link for that coupon in your cart.